# How to read two lines from a file and create dynamics keys in a for-loop?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dictionary, defaultdict

In the following data, I am trying to run a simple markov model.

**Say I have a data with following structure:**

```
pos   M1  M2  M3  M4  M5  M6  M7  M8  hybrid_block    S1    S2    S3    S4  S5  S6  S7  S8
1     A   T   T   A   A   G   A   C       A|C         C     G     C     T    T   A   G   A
2     T   G   C   T   G   T   T   G       T|A         A     T     A     T    C   A   A   T
3     C   A   A   C   A   G   T   C       C|G         G     A     C     G    C   G   C   G
4     G   T   G   T   A   T   C   T       G|T         C     T     T     T    A   T   C   T
```

**Block M** represents data from one set of catergories, so does **block S**.

The data are the `strings` which are made by connecting letter along the position line. So, the **string value for M1 is A-T-C-G**, and so is for every other block.

There is also one `hybrid block` that has two string which is read in same way. **The question is I want to find which string in the hybrid block most likely came from which block (M vs. S)?**

I am trying to build a markov model which can help me identify which string in `hybrid block` came from which blocks. In this example I can tell that in **hybrid block** `ATCG` came from `block M` and `CAGT` came from `block S`.

**I am breaking the problem into different parts** to read and mine the data:

**Problem level 01:**

- First I read the first line (the header) and create `unique keys` for all the columns.
- Then I read the 2nd line (`pos` with value **1**) and create another key. In the same line I read the value from `hybrid_block` and read the strings value in it. The `pipe |` is just a separator, so two strings are in `index 0 and 2` as `A` and `C`. So, all I want from this line is a

`defaultdict(<class 'dict'>, {'M1': ['A'], 'M2': ['T'], 'M3': ['T']...., 'hybrid_block': ['A'], ['C']...}`

As, I progress with reading the line, I want to append the strings values from each column and finally create.

`defaultdict(<class 'dict'>, {'M1': ['A', 'T', 'C', 'G'], 'M2': ['T', 'G', 'A', 'T'], 'M3': ['T', 'C', 'A', 'G']...., 'hybrid_block': ['A', 'T', 'C', 'G'], ['C', 'A', 'G', 'T']...}`

Problem level 02:

- I read the data in `hybrid_block` for the first line which are `A and C`.
- Now, I want to create `keys' but unlike fixed keys, these key will be generated while reading the data from`hybrid_blocks`.
  For the first line since there are no preceding line the`keys`will simply be`AgA`and`CgC`which means (A given A, and C given C), and for the values I count the number of`A`in`block M`and`block S`. So, the data will be stored as:

`defaultdict(<class 'dict'>, {'M': {'AgA': [4], 'CgC': [1]}, 'S': {'AgA': 2, 'CgC': 2}}`

As, I read through other lines I want to create new keys based on what are the strings in `hybrid block` and count the number of times that string was present in `M vs S` block given the string in preceeding line. That means the `keys` while reading `line 2` would be `TgA' which means (T given A) and AgC. For the values inside this key I count the number of times I found`T in this line, after A in the previous line`and same for`AcG`.

The `defaultdict` after reading 3 lines would be.

`defaultdict(<class 'dict'>, {'M': {'AgA': 4, 'TgA':3, 'CgT':2}, {'CgC': [1], 'AgC':0, 'GgA':0}, 'S': {'AgA': 2, 'TgA':1, 'CgT':0}, {'CgC': 2, 'AgC':2, 'GgA':2}}`

I understand this looks too complicated. I went through several `dictionary` and `defaultdict` tutorial but couldn't find a way of doing this.

Solution to any part if not both is highly appreciated.

Comment: maybe use `pandas` and read this file as `CSV` file with `space as separator`. And you get `DataFrame` which gives easy access to columns - `df["M1"]` - and it can do many things without `for` loop.

Comment: I was wondering about `pandas` but how would it be possible to run a `markov chain` on the given data. I have read `pandas` but haven't seen any method that I can use to apply (`AgA, TgA, CgT`)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## `pandas` setup

```
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

txt = """pos   M1  M2  M3  M4  M5  M6  M7  M8  hybrid_block    S1    S2    S3    S4  S5  S6  S7  S8
1     A   T   T   A   A   G   A   C       A|C         C     G     C     T    T   A   G   A
2     T   G   C   T   G   T   T   G       T|A         A     T     A     T    C   A   A   T
3     C   A   A   C   A   G   T   C       C|G         G     A     C     G    C   G   C   G
4     G   T   G   T   A   T   C   T       G|T         C     T     T     T    A   T   C   T """

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(txt), delim_whitespace=True, index_col='pos')

df
```

[image]

## solution

### mostly `pandas` with some `numpy`

---

- split hybrid column
- prepend identical first row
- add with shifted version of self to get `'AgA'` type strings

---

```
d1 = pd.concat([df.loc[[1]].rename(index={1: 0}), df])

d1 = pd.concat([
        df.filter(like='M'),
        df.hybrid_block.str.split('|', expand=True).rename(columns='H{}'.format),
        df.filter(like='S')
    ], axis=1)

d1 = pd.concat([d1.loc[[1]].rename(index={1: 0}), d1])
d1 = d1.add('g').add(d1.shift()).dropna()

d1
```

[image]

Assign convenient blocks to their own variable names

```
m = d1.filter(like='M')
s = d1.filter(like='S')
h = d1.filter(like='H')
```

Count how many are in each block and concatenate

```
mcounts = pd.DataFrame(
    (m.values[:, :, None] == h.values[:, None, :]).sum(1),
    h.index, h.columns
)
scounts = pd.DataFrame(
    (s.values[:, :, None] == h.values[:, None, :]).sum(1),
    h.index, h.columns
)

counts = pd.concat([mcounts, scounts], axis=1, keys=['M', 'S'])
counts
```

[image]

If you really want a dictionary

```
d = defaultdict(lambda:defaultdict(list))

dict_df = counts.stack().join(h.stack().rename('condition')).unstack()
for pos, row in dict_df.iterrows():
    d['M']['H0'].append((row.loc[('condition', 'H0')], row.loc[('M', 'H0')]))
    d['S']['H0'].append((row.loc[('condition', 'H0')], row.loc[('S', 'H0')]))
    d['M']['H1'].append((row.loc[('condition', 'H1')], row.loc[('M', 'H1')]))
    d['S']['H1'].append((row.loc[('condition', 'H1')], row.loc[('S', 'H1')]))

dict(d)

{'M': defaultdict(list,
             {'H0': [('AgA', 4), ('TgA', 3), ('CgT', 2), ('GgC', 1)],
              'H1': [('CgC', 1), ('AgC', 0), ('GgA', 0), ('TgG', 1)]}),
 'S': defaultdict(list,
             {'H0': [('AgA', 2), ('TgA', 1), ('CgT', 0), ('GgC', 0)],
              'H1': [('CgC', 2), ('AgC', 2), ('GgA', 2), ('TgG', 3)]})}
```

Comment: Thanks for being awesome. You gave me more than I had anticipated. There might be some challenges for me downstream since my data structure is little different (there will be some missing data and there is some group along the position too). I am reading you code and trying to follow `pandas, defaultdict` tutorial and example to accomplish what I want. If there is any problem I will reach out to you. Additionally, you have pulled some many function that I was not aware of like `loc`,  `stack` etc. Thanks again. **Could you suggest me some advanced reads on pandas, defaultdict**.

Comment: Mr. @piRSquared. Can you please look into the following problem. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42012730/how-to-read-two-lines-from-a-file-and-create-dynamics-keys-in-a-for-loop-using-p

Comment: @everestial007 I will take a look when I can. I wouldn't expect it for several days.

Comment: ok thanks. At the mean time I will try to see if I can find solutions to some parts of the problem.

Comment: is there **a method to do applymap along with groupby in pandas**. I am trying to find an example or tutorial for this purpose, but not finding. Hope you would knew. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42150453/how-to-run-applymap-function-along-with-groupy-in-pandas-dataframe  Thanks !

Comment: Could you please add some explanation for the above count process in pandas? mainly at the title `Count how many are in each block and concatenate`.  **Else, give some ideas on this question** http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42381617/how-to-count-the-number-of-values-of-an-item-in-one-column-in-another-column-usi