# How to read two lines from a file and create dynamics keys in a for-loop, a follow-up

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dictionary, defaultdict

This question follows the problem in question: [How to read two lines from a file and create dynamics keys in a for-loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41929351/868546)

But, the nature of the problem has evolved to certain complexity that I want to address.

Below is the structure of my data separated by space.

```
chr pos         M1  M2  Mk  Mg1  F1_hybrid     F1_PG    F1_block    S1  Sk1   S2    Sj
2   16229767    T/T T/T T/T G/T C|T 1|0 726  .  T/C T/C T/C
2   16229783    C/C C/C C/C A/C G|C 0|1 726 G/C G/C G/C C|G
2   16229992    A/A A/A A/A G/A G|A 1|0 726 A/A A/A A/A A|G
2   16230007    T/T T/T T/T A/T A|T 1|0 726 A|T A|T A|T A|T
2   16230011    G/G G/G G/G G/G C|G 1|0 726 G/C C|G C|G G/C
2   16230049    A/A A/A A/A A/A T|A 1|0 726 A|T .   A/T A/T
2   16230174    .   .   .   C/C T|C 1|0 726 C|T T|C T|C C|T
2   16230190    A/A A/A A/A A/A T|A 1|0 726 T|G G|T T|G T|G
2   16230260    A/A A/A A/A A/A G|A 1|0 726 G/G G/G G/G G/G
```

Explanation:

- there are two major categories of data in the above file. Data from `Group M` have sample name starting with **M**, and similarly `group S` that has several columns names starting with **S**.
- And there is a hybrid column (represented by **F1_hybrid**).
- the data is the string along the position line. The F1_hybrid is phased with pipe (|) distinguishing the two letters. So, the two strings values from F1 are `C-G-G-A-C-T-T-T-G`, while another string value is T-C-A-T-G-A-C-A-A. One of this string is from **M-group** while the other is from **S-group** but **I need to do some statistical analyses to do so. However, I can tell that visually that T-C-A-T-G-A-C-A-A string most likely came from M-group.**

Procedure:

- I read the first line and create a unique keys using the column information.
- Then I read the second and 3rd line and the values in F1_hybrid, which is C|T with G|C. Now, I need to calculate how many GgC (explained as G given C) vs. CgT (C given T) exist between M-group vs. S group.
- Then read 3rd (G|C) with 4th (G|A) line in F1_hybrid. So, the states are GgG and AgC. Similarly, **I now count have many GcG vs. AgC exist in M vs. S group.**

Therefore, I am trying to build a `Markov-model` which counts the number of state for a phased string from F1 and taking the observed counts in `group M` vs `group S`.

I am now explaining, how to count the number of any XgY (X given Y) based on F1_hyrbid:

- **It important to note the conditions before doing the count.**
  The existing condition may be phased (which is represented by having pipe) vs. unphased (if the if two line have at least one slash (/).

**Condition 01:**

The `M1` sample has **state as (T/T with C/C)** for 2nd and 3rd line. since the separator is a **slash (/)** and not **pipe (|)** we cannot tell which exact state M1-sample is in. But, we can create combination matrix (for previous state with present state)

```
    T     T
C  CgT   CgT
C  CgT   CgT
```

Now, we can tell that there are **4 total CgT**

and we keep doing the same matrix if this condition meets.

**Condition 02**

Same is the case for other samples from Group M, except for Mg1 where the G/T is preceeding A/C. So, the matrix is:

```
    G     T
A  AgG   AgT
C  CgG   CgT
```

So, here we observed 1 count of CgT.

**Condition 03:**

But, if the earlier state - present state are phased by pipe in both states **(like A|T at position 16230007 with C|G at position 16230011 for sample Sk1)** we can do a direct count of phase state of observed state at that position, that there are only CgA and GgT, so count of CgT is 0.

**Condition 04:**
If one of the state has pipe (|) but other has slash (/), the condition will be same as both state having slash.

**Condition 05:**
If any of the previous_state or present_state is period(.) the observation count is automatically zero (0) for the state expected from F1_hybrid.

**So, the expected output should be something like this:**

```
pos     M1  M2  Mk  Mg1 H0  H1  S1  Sk1 S2  Sj
16..9783    4-CgT   4-CgT   4-CgT   1-CgT   GgC CgT 0   1-CgT   1-CgT   1-CgT
16..9992    4-AgC   4-AgC   4-AgC   2-AgC   GgG AgC 1-AgC   1-AgC   1-AgC   1-AgC,1-GgG
16..0007    4-TgA   4-TgA   4-TgA   1-AgG,1-TgA AgG TgA 2-TgA   2-TgA   2-TgA1  1-TgA
..................contd
```

Or, the values in dictionary format for each column would equally work. Something like `['4-CgT','4-CgT','4-CgT','4-CgT']` for first M1 at position 16..9783 and same for other.

Comment: This reads like an assignment and not like a question at all. Why is this tagged with python, pandas, numpy? Would you like someone to write code in that language?

Comment: First: No, it's not an assignment. I am a biologist working on my data analyses. I know python at intermediate level now, and this is one of the problems from which I can and want to learn a lot.    Second: This has multiple tags because different people had different experience with different packages. I am trying to see if I can do something different - which is also a learning experience. Finally, again - this is not an assignment and I don't get grades from it. Please stop assuming so.

Comment: You could ask at https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/questions

Comment: This problem is too long and not written clearly. Suggest you simplify and shorten it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question is a bit old, but interesting because you have a very clear specification and you need help to write the code. I will expose a solution following a top-down approach, which is a very well known method, using plain old python. It shouldn't be difficult to adapt to pandas.

The top-down approach means to me: **if you don't know how to write it, just name it!**

You have a file (or a string) as input, and you want to output a file (or a string). It seems quite simple, but you want to merge pairs of rows to build every new row. The idea is:

1. get the rows of the input, as dictionaries
2. take them by two
3. build a new row for each pair
4. output the result

You don't know for now how to write the generator of rows. You don't know either how to build a new row for each pair. Don't stay blocked by the difficulties, just name the solutions. Imagine you have a function `get_rows` and a function `build_new_row`. Let's write this:

```
def build_new_rows(f):
    """generate the new rows. Output may be redirected to a file"""
    rows = get_rows(f) # get a generator on rows = dictionaries.
    r1 = next(rows) # store the first row
    for r2 in rows: # for every following row
        yield build_new_row(r1, r2) # yield a new row built of the previous stored row and the current row.
        r1 = r2 # store the current row, which becomes the previous row
```

Now, examine the two "missing" functions: `get_rows` and `build_new_row`.
The function `get_rows` is quite easy to write. Here's the main part:

```
header = process_line(next(f))
for line in f:
    yield {k:v for k,v in zip(header, process_line(line))}
```

where `process_line` just splits the line on space, e.g. with a `re.split("\s+", line.strip())`.

The second part is `build_new_row`. Still the top-down approach: you need to build H0 and H1 from your expected table, and then to build the count of H1 for every M and S according to the conditions you exposed. Pretend you have a `pipe_compute` function that compute H0 and H1, and a `build_count` function that builds the count of H1 for every M and S:

```
def build_new_row(r1, r2):
    """build a row"""
    h0, h1 = pipe_compute(r1["F1_hybrid"], r2["F1_hybrid"])

    # initialize the dict whith the pos, H0 and H1
    new_row = {"pos":r2["pos"], "H0":h0, "H1":h1}

    for key in r1.keys():
        if key[0] in ("M", "S"):
            new_row[key] = build_count(r1[key], r2[key], h1)

    return new_row
```

You have almost everything now. Take a look at `pipe_compute`: it's exactly what you have written in your condition 03.

```
def pipe_compute(v1, v2):
    """build H0 H1 according to condition 03"""
    xs = v1.split("|")
    ys = v2.split("|")
    return [ys[0]+"g"+xs[0], ys[1]+"g"+xs[1]]
```

And for `buid_count`, stick to the top-down approach:

```
def build_count(v1, v2, to_count):
    """nothing funny here: just follow the conditions"""
    if is_slash_count(v1, v2): # are conditions 01, 02, 04 true ?
        c = slash_count(v1, v2)[to_count] # count how many "to_count" we find in the 2 x 2 table of condtions 01 or 02.
    elif "|" in v1 and "|" in v2: # condition 03
        c = pipe_count(v1, v2)[to_count]
    elif "." in v1 or "." in v2: # condition 05
        return '0'
    else:
        raise Exception(v1, v2)

    return "{}-{}".format(c, to_count) # n-XgY
```

We are still going down. When do we have `is_slash_count`? Two slashes (conditions 01 and 02) or one slash and one pipe (condition 04):

```
def is_slash_count(v1, v2):
    """conditions 01, 02, 04"""
    return "/" in v1 and "/" in v2 or "/" in v1 and "|" in v2 or "|" in v1 and "/" in v2
```

The function `slash_count` is simply the 2 x 2 table of conditions 01 and 02:

```
def slash_count(v1, v2):
    """count according to conditions 01, 02, 04"""
    cnt = collections.Counter()
    for x in re.split("[|/]", v1): # cartesian product
        for y in re.split("[|/]", v2): # cartesian product
            cnt[y+"g"+x] += 1
    return cnt # a dictionary XgY -> count(XgY)
```

The function `pipe_count` is even simpler, because you just have to count the result of `pipe_compute`:

```
def pipe_count(v1, v2):
    """count according to condition 03"""
    return collections.Counter(pipe_compute(v1, v2))
```

Now you're done (and down). I get this result, which is slightly different from your expectation, but you certainly have already seen my mistake(s?):

```
pos M1  M2  Mk  Mg1 H0  H1  S1  Sk1 S2  Sj
16229783    4-CgT   4-CgT   4-CgT   1-CgT   GgC CgT 0   1-CgT   1-CgT   1-CgT
16229992    4-AgC   4-AgC   4-AgC   1-AgC   GgG AgC 2-AgC   2-AgC   2-AgC   1-AgC
16230007    4-TgA   4-TgA   4-TgA   1-TgA   AgG TgA 2-TgA   2-TgA   2-TgA   0-TgA
16230011    4-GgT   4-GgT   4-GgT   2-GgT   CgA GgT 1-GgT   1-GgT   1-GgT   1-GgT
16230049    4-AgG   4-AgG   4-AgG   4-AgG   TgC AgG 1-AgG   0   1-AgG   1-AgG
16230174    0   0   0   4-CgA   TgT CgA 1-CgA   0   1-CgA   1-CgA
16230190    0   0   0   4-AgC   TgT AgC 0-AgC   0-AgC   0-AgC   0-AgC
16230260    4-AgA   4-AgA   4-AgA   4-AgA   GgT AgA 0-AgA   0-AgA   0-AgA   0-AgA
```

Bonus: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lVZtb@M2DP6eX0G4H5qgsWO7XXvNUAxFsKU3oLgB7YcNucBwbDlW41iZrLxd09/ekZLtOD3fhgWgI4lvj0iK0mqvUpFfvr@fQSRins@HsFaJ/alzBqlSq2I4GBQqjBZiw2SSia0TieXg7zUrFBd5MbjyXc@/uXQHqdjaStiShbGttsLOeM4KO5FiaYd2wjNmh3lsR8hXzI73ebjkUWEv2L6weU4iQtqZECt7XSAIe9Xp8OVKSAVcVCPJqlEksoxFGkG1VOzrYVRsOh21U3AHlmVFqYSVKKD6PXpIPtICaY6T37wg3c8kjzUbZ3@My8EsE9GCxk8o9rTwaOTr@UuH/r1r37@9ub6hpefBc01jpNHhGbyDCzf@NYBD/FFFDd1Pl6Q7wvWK7pHGhxG4B0/rjmle0ugwPure3moo94P7msZEh/vab5N3f9S9dF33O8z3RA3MNG5QQ9ejOKCv8Qkhtlq3xKppfNwv6l7dfsRM9NzEjP4cLaMxHXW9myvSdRpE8XrGWFW6FHOaE42amL1b97/8PhNWrT8mOur61626zTh/iAUWXacTswRma57FQc62gRTbopv0hh0yhfw5y5nEkwAqZYACQAIOfFmr1VrBMtzDjGG9x1ximbMYlIAQ6BSRbbJB8ljfc6Yq22bZw8Wc7VSXVs0aniyQPvBcKxkI9NtzlsWnGLvS66Nsr5bR9qRvttNwVm9kXG1EA6LjrmFCxhcMxOwF4TsV5jMoVhlXIHII8z1Owog5mrOSImJFEVDTQIdZuJzFIdBsiFFwtFrX@lpcWH296hRK8lW31@to9RSbDpOo2LTT1WFIescgaOsYhuRjDF4Xw42WWPQ3JPANbRub/VOT9On13lqyW0WuDozmYtKQNwTPARViQAqxZLAJM2yfJlbS/xl8B/vZEvNuqsGwq5ilbh9SSsKKr1hQyqGziVW3LWtKnk8Wyric4Wa44mHGvxnbMY8UbFOuUj3FttiHBxezEcODp1XK7aDDVwvZ1pAs0wCdWA@uNSRA1oOHA@@tU4cW@7guMM@hjt7tHSPME2JO3Cnxu9YjZtB6shoCDa8TlJyiaxPZSKxzRVulVb1FM0i9cnuSqbXMK2WTlJMwbTAnm@9ykvFCQRhFQtJ1R0crEnnM6TYB97IK/I6O18arau9gmTra62X/43IJZbIvcKcX1ty62NGoj/ITr17wptNm6ZgNGpB9xGEWjnBzoVJCmKxzPC4pk3gaXtYIPsHrD3NEKayh1xWDAedFUGRhkZ546A2xHkLZVAEXOS76dq9AyTWDX@B3so@XMx4U5dQ5inDTLRYnFeYp0OsBB4DPAGxfCNeqeBZsGfYELDEsAILsww5JhTNsEyLRcCo0gKXk4nn4HgXLcF8YbjKy8XTFVjN/qL0fU3gCuyyIVtQNy05lGRFUk4@Gfzq2RZPuc/e8NFGwY0HLkBcMft1FbEV6lduTmrVe3@zXN8vBs7MMVTdqpB995vaf879MpfwglVWJtOayviNKX4OTqJUzX@900BpQzTq0ahlU/w6J6qD9fLWhjHJ6qDVedM6ILDDZPXbunW4u9UUwOQym2Ec2XqONkNi@Xcz/0G3Q42RvzuQULu7Aa0YLmSed5P9usdFCKostW2trUz3jdxnyvGqgCUaGC@cJb7t8/vlLFx@1VB/66qAHbv0saN63p1ei6d7YdB89/fX1d6G/c72EXd20dOrM5rswf1r26cUyB4Wu/9MLOh7CJJ4spuYKoOAbt1NT61vJlcaAD3LHTLr4TMfLOxZr1YcYj96SVu/Ov6rzXkOnlMZr1RhsPGTIyw/eVW36FeiupPjiSQ8C6itBAHd3cB4EFO0gODcGTOg77@//AA)

What is important is, beyond the solution to this specific problem, the method I used and which is widely used in software development. The code may be improved a lot.

Comment: "[I]f you don't know how to write it, just name it!" is such excellent advice!