# How to count the number of times a item/value from a particular column is repeated in another/other column of a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, string, pandas, dataframe, count

**I have a pandas data like following:**

```
MA1     MA2     MA3        Sp3              Sp4     Sp6            F1_x     F1_y
TgT,TgT   TgT,TgT       TgT,TgT,TgT   TgT,TgC           TgT,CgC    TgT,TgC,CgT,CgC     CgC     TgT
CgT       CgT,CgT,CgT   CgT,CgT       CgT,CgC,GgT,GgC   CgT,GgC    GgT,GgC,CgT         GgC      CgT
TgC       TgG,TgC       TgC           TgC,CgG           CgG,CgG    TgG,TgC             CgG      TgC
```

**Problem 01:**

- I will read the string values in **F1_x and F1_y** and want to count **how many of F1_x vs y are in other columns?**
- the counts of F1_x will be written first separated by pipe (|).

**Output: For the first line would be**

```
MA1  MA2     MA3      Sp3   Sp4   Sp6      F1_x    F1_y
0|2      0|2      0|3     0|1    1|1       1|1     CgC     TgT
```

**Problem 02:** Additionally, I want to create another dataframe where the counts are done for **M-type vs. S-type column**.

**Output: for the first line would be**

```
        like_M      like_S
        x   y       x   y
         0|7         1|3
```

or,

```
    like_M      like_S     F1_x    F1_y
    0|7         1|3        CgC     TgT
```

I tried a method using for-loop which was quite extensive because my data are huge. I tried to take this method given by @piRSquared in this question: [How to read two lines from a file and create dynamics keys in a for-loop using python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41929351/how-to-read-two-lines-from-a-file-and-create-dynamics-keys-in-a-for-loop-using-p)
but, couldn't work it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

consider the `numpy` based helper function `count_in`

```
def count_in(clst, cols):
    cols = np.asarray(cols)
    c1 = np.core.defchararray.split(np.asarray(clst).astype(str), ',')
    l = np.array([len(i) for i in c1])
    s = np.concatenate(c1)
    r = np.arange(len(cols))
    c = (s[:, None] == cols[r.repeat(l)]).cumsum(0)

    z = np.zeros(cols.shape[1], dtype=int)
    counts = np.diff(np.vstack([z, c[l.cumsum() - 1]]), axis=0).astype(str)
    return pd.Series(counts.tolist(), clst.index).str.join('|')
```

then `apply`

```
cols = ['F1_x', 'F1_y']
d1 = df.drop(cols, 1).apply(count_in, cols=df[cols])
d1.join(df[cols])

   MA1  MA2  MA3  Sp3  Sp4  Sp6 F1_x F1_y
0  0|2  0|2  0|3  0|1  1|1  1|1  CgC  TgT
1  0|1  0|3  0|2  1|1  1|1  1|1  GgC  CgT
2  0|1  0|1  0|1  1|1  2|0  0|1  CgG  TgC
```

Then

```
d2 = d1.stack().str.split('|', expand=True).astype(int)
d3 = d2.groupby(
    [d2.index.get_level_values(0), d2.index.get_level_values(1).str[0]]
).sum()
pd.Series(
    d3.astype(str).values.tolist(), d3.index
).str.join('|').unstack().rename(columns='like_{}'.format).join(df[cols])

  like_M like_S F1_x F1_y
0    0|7    2|3  CgC  TgT
1    0|6    3|3  GgC  CgT
2    0|3    3|2  CgG  TgC
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. If you have sometime, can you please add some explanation. I am trying to read pandas doc and your script to find what each piece of code is doing. Any info would be helpful.